# Azure Resource Manager Service Connection not connecting

Tags: azure-devops

We currently have one DevOps repository, with a functional CI/CD pipeline. We have another website hosted on a different instance (and different region) on Azure. We are trying to use our existing repo to deploy to the other Azure instance, but it is giving is the following message:

Failed to query service connection API: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/c50b0601-a951-446c-b637-afa8d6bb1a1d?api-version=2016-06-01'. Status Code: 'Forbidden', Response from server: '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client '2317de35-b2c2-4e32-a922-e0d076a429f5' with object id '2317de35-b2c2-4e32-a922-e0d076a429f5' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/read' over scope '/subscriptions/c50b0601-a951-446c-b637-afa8d6bb1a1d'."}}'

I have tried all of the recommended trouble-shooting, making sure that the user is in a Global Administrator role and what-not, but still not luck. The secondary Azure subscription that we are hoping to push our builds to is a trial account. I'm not sure if it being a trial account matters.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I came across the same error. It turns out that, as the error message states, the service principal didn't have Read permission over the subscription. So the solution was to go to Azure Portal, select the subscription, select IAM and assign the role Reader to my service principal. Full explanation on here:
https://clydedz.medium.com/connecting-azure-devops-with-azure-46a908e3048f

Comment: You must pay to read this article :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. There are one repository and two instances of the application on the Azure portal. For the first instance, the subscription Pay-As-You-Go is used, and there were no problems for it when creating the service connection and CI/CD settings. For the second instance, a free subscription is used and when trying to create a new service connection (Azure Resource Manager) I get the same error.

I tried to do it with the permissions of Owner and Contributor

**UPD**: I was helped by the re-creation of the application in the azure portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to save without verification if the Service Principle will not require permissions at the Subscription level. Like for example providing access to a Keyvault.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the service connection for the second instance is correctly added in project settings:

[image]